# Excel Finding Consecutive Phone Numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is there a way in excel if I have a bunch of phone numbers in 1234567890 format, that I could find ranges and paste in the format of XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX?

I tried with some mid formulas but it's not working quite right.

```
=IF(A63=A62+1,A62 & "-" & A63,"NO ")
```

EDIT:

1234567890

1234567891

1234567892

1234567893

1234567897

1234567898

1234567899

5552221212

5552221213

Should look like:

1234567890-7893

1234567897-7899

5552221212-1213

EDIT 2:

If you throw in an odd ball between the mix say, 5555555555, I don't want to make 5555555555 link with any of those numbers.

For example, currently, I am looking at this further down on my spreadsheet: =IF(A209=A208+1,A208 & "-" & A209,A209). Basically, it posts the TN above it with the number after. What happens is going down the list above I'd get

1234567890 - 1234567891

1234567891 - 1234567892

Is there a way to make it show only 1234567890 - 1234567892?

Comment: Are you only wanting this to be don on consecutive numbers? How does the consecutive part come into play?

Comment: The formula and the description is totally different; you say you want to change the format of cell content, but the formula concatenates two cells, please clarify.

Comment: Do you just want to add the " - " before the last four numbers? If not I dont really get your question.

Comment: I added the example. Sorry for confusion! Ran off to a meeting before I could add the example.

Comment: Also, numbers are presorted and are in order.

Answer (score 0):

If all the numbers are of the same format and you always want the "-" inserted before the last four numbers this will do the trick

In an excel formula:

```
=LEFT(A1;6) & "-" & RIGHT(A1;4)
```

In VBA

```
Dim text1 As String, text2 As String

For i = 1 To NumberOfRows

text1 = Cells(A,i)
text2 = Left(text1,6) + "-" + Right(text1,4)

Next i
```

Comment: To add to this, how do you find them? I'm able to do something similar to this but if you throw in an odd ball between the mix say, 5555555555, I don't want to make 5555555555 link with any of those numbers. For example, currently, I am looking at this further down on my spreadsheet:  =IF(A209=A208+1,A208 & "-" & A209,A209). Basically, it posts the TN above it with the number after. What happens is going down the list above I'd get 1234567890 - 1234567891, 1234567891 - 1234567892. Is there a way to make it show only 1234567890 - 1234567892?

Comment: Could you rephrase that? I dont really understand.
For the excel formula, you have to put the formula - lets say - right to your original data; change the "A1" to the according cell and then use auto fill on your column.

Comment: Imagine if you have a list of customer phone numbers for a large account. They are not 555-555-0000 thru 555-555-0099. Instead, imagine they are 0000, 0001, 0003, 0004, 0005, 0010, 0020, 0021.

If I could make some kind of formula that can find the range and put them together.

555-555-0000 - 0001

555-555-0003 - 0005

555-555-0010

555-555-0020 - 0021